# upload text file to pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, text

I am having trouble with a process ive been doing copule of times before. I am a new user of Python and Jupyter notebook, and I am trying to convert my text file which contains this data: (25k lists):

```
[X,
Y],
[Z,
X,
Y,
Z],
```

This is the file structure and I am trying to convert it to a pandas dataframe (wide-columnstore) with this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import ast
import json 

data = open("C:/Users/itamar/Desktop/SuperMushlam/How To Use Apriori Algorithm A-Z/sss.txt", 'r', encoding = 'windows-1255', errors='ignore').read().replace("\r","").replace("\n","")

remove_doulequotes = data.replace('""', '').replace('"', '')

list_of_str = list(map(lambda x: '"{x}"'.format(x=x), remove_doulequotes.split(",")))

final_data = ", ".join(list_of_str).replace('"[[', '[["').replace(']"','"]').replace(']]"', '"]]').replace('"[', '["').replace(']"]', '"]]')

data_in_list = ast.literal_eval(final_data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data_in_list)

df
```

It worked before, so I am trying to understand where is my problem during the process. 
This is the error message I get:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-d41ed8f6586e> in <module>
     11 final_data = ", ".join(list_of_str).replace('"[[', '[["').replace(']"','"]').replace(']]"', '"]]').replace('"[', '["').replace(']"]', '"]]')
     12 
---> 13 data_in_list = ast.literal_eval(final_data)
     14 
     15 df = pd.DataFrame(data_in_list)

~\Anaconda3\lib\ast.py in literal_eval(node_or_string)
     44     """
     45     if isinstance(node_or_string, str):
---> 46         node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
     47     if isinstance(node_or_string, Expression):
     48         node_or_string = node_or_string.body

~\Anaconda3\lib\ast.py in parse(source, filename, mode)
     33     Equivalent to compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST).
     34     """
---> 35     return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
     36 
     37 

MemoryError:
```

Any suggestions? I am not sure where is my problem. Thanks a lot!

Thats what I need:

[image]

Comment: Could you update this question with an example of how you expect your DataFrame to look like after running this code on it? like is each list in the file going to be a row or a column or something else?

Comment: Hey sure. as I wrote I need a widecolumnstore which each list is a row and each value is a cell. I will edit it now

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your whole text file matches the pattern you described:

```
[X,
Y],
[Z,
X,
Y,
Z],
```

You might be able to build the DataFrame you are looking for via the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df_l = []
tmp_l = []
filename = "C:/Users/itamar/Desktop/SuperMushlam/How To Use Apriori Algorithm A-Z/sss.txt"
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        value = ''.join([c for c in line if c not in '[ ] ,'.split()]).strip('\n')
        value = float(value) if value.replace('.','',1).isdigit() else value
        tmp_l.append(value)
        if ']' in line:
            df_l.append(pd.DataFrame(tmp_l).T)
            tmp_l = []

df = pd.concat(df_l, ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   0  1    2    3
0  X  Y  NaN  NaN
1  Z  X    Y    Z

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The above solution makes a list of single row DataFrames (`df_l`) where each DataFrame is created from each list in your .txt file. It them uses `pd.concat` to join all those one row DataFrames in `df_l` into a single `df`. This solution also makes the assumptions that each line of your .txt file contains exactly one list item and the characters `"["`, `","` and `"]"` are not to be included in that item.